# Symbols are not loaded dynamically to AppDomain with assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, appdomain, pdb-files

I am loading my assemblies dynamically to my app domain, i also load the symbols, but for some reason the symbols are not loaded (on exceptions i can't get the line numbers)

```
 var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(_assemblyDictionary[requestedAssembly]);
 var symbols = File.ReadAllBytes((Path.ChangeExtension(_assemblyDictionary[requestedAssembly], "pdb")));
 myAssembly = currentDomain.Load(bytes, symbols);
```

I tried to use ChkMatch to check if the dll's matches the pdb's and got a match.

why does this happens and how can i fix it?

Comment: I've quickly hacked together something that loads a DLL into memory like you do, but I cannot reproduce that problem... symbols are loaded just fine. Perhaps give us a minimally-complete code example that exhibits the problem: The code should show what DLL's you've got, how you load them into memory, and how exactly you invoke the code that throws the exception. Perhaps also verify in the debug output (during debugging) that the DLL wasn't already loaded into memory before your call to `AppDomain.Load`.

Comment: Although I personally like your question and have upvoted it, I've also close-voted it because your code example is *not* a minimally complete one that exhibits the problem; and that is a requirement here on SO.

Comment: It's pretty long code to put here, before i load the dll's i scan the assemblies directory with Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad, could it cause the problem?

Comment: You don't need to post your complete code; there are two ways to arrive at a minimally complete code example: (1) Start a new project and focus on the dynamic loading of an assembly and its symbols in the same way as you've shown here; your project should do nothing else that is not required to achieve that. See if the problem persists. If not, on to... (2) take a copy of your current code, and try to remove everything that is not related to the assembly loading. Every so often check if the problem goes away. When it does, note what caused the change. If if doesn't, compare to (1).

Comment: Concerning `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad`: If you already suspect this might cause the issue, why don't you verify whether it does or not? Try loading some assembly *without* doing an `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad` beforehand and see whether it resolves your issue.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i found the problem, there was actually another place loading assemblies too that i didn't take into consideration, added the pdb there too and it worked, Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad was not the issue.